# Yes indeed, an Outlaw from the past

Tags: word, knowledge

I am an outlaw from way past. Not real though.

> Look at me forward, backward, or upside down, I remain exactly the
>   same. Yes indeed, no change.

Can you guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mindbender is surely

> [SINIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinis_(mythology)) the pinebender, who tied people to bent pine trees, and then let go!

<sup>Only found from researching the [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92602/yes-indeed-an-outlaw-from-the-past#comment266689_92604)</sup>

Comment: Sinis includes Si (Yes Indeed)

Answer (score 7):

Well, I can guess, but with no conviction whatsoever, since this answer is 95% google-fu.

Are you, by any chance,

> [Soxos](https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-gb/character/eu/arthas/soxos)?

That might figure, because

> he seems to be a fictional outlaw, his name is palindromic, and it stays the same even if you turn your monitor upside-down.

Comment: I somehow didn't think it would be that simple

Comment: On the right track @Bass. Try Greek Mythology Outlaws